# Unable to load Winforms designer in VS2012 due to old assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, advantage-database-server

I don't think this is anything specific to Advantage Database Server but I have recently upgrade to a new version of the Advantage .NET provider (now version `11.10.2.21`).

The solution builds perfectly yet when I load certain winforms in the VS2012 designer I get the following error :-

> Could not load file or assembly 'Advantage.Data.Provider, Version=11.10.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e33137c86a38dc06' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Version `11.10.2.1` was the old version that I uninstalled before installing `11.10.2.21`

When I try and find the reference to the old assembly in Find (entire solution) it doesn't find anything.

Does anyone know where this reference could be located? I want to remove it so that I can continue to work on my forms.

Comment: You didn't manage to uninstall the old version completely, apparently the old reference assembly is still around.  Remove the assembly reference and add it back, now using the new version.

Comment: I did that but it still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally!

I use DevExpress controls and they have a reference to that version of Advantage Database Server in their XPO product (which I don't use directly).

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where you installed it. What you need to find is the folder you installed this to and then look in that folder for the .dll file for the assembly you need. (In my experience this will be in a lib/library folder but your results may vary) Note the full file path of the .dll file once you find it. Then when trying to add the new reference navigate to that file path and add the .dll file

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. I don't want to find the old .DLL file. It should be picking up the new version but I cannot find where the form/designer has stored the old reference so that I can remove/edit it to be the new reference.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you find the old one, if you uninstalled the old version the .dll was probably removed. I'm saying find the new .dll and then add that as a reference

Comment: Hi, I have added a reference to the new version of the dll and uninstalled the old one but the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you removed the old reference from the project?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can tell i.e. removed from the references tree node.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different grep tool (Like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and search in all your resx files of the project for the text (or part thereof)

> Advantage.Data.Provider, Version=11.10.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e33137c86a38dc06

With uninstalling the previous version and installing the new version, those references probably didn't get updated.
Recommended solution would be to find all those entries and replace them with the new version of that text (viewable by opening a .resx file of a form that has a control from the new version on it)

Comment: Good shout. I have checked and changed all references to 11.10.2.1 to be 11.10.2.21 (culture and publickeytoken are the same) but I still get the same error. I have also checked and changed hidden files too.  Could it be a registry entry?

Comment: There is also nothing in the GAC for version 11.10.2.1. I can't think of where the reference could be.

Comment: I have also searched in the registry and there are no entries for that version.

Comment: Have a look at the stack trace of the exception, that might help to identify what or where that reference lives. Additionally you can use ProcMon to try and see where it is looking for that dll